# How to check the process running on specific port in NSIS

Tags: installation, nsis, port80

I'm using NSIS to develop an installer for my application. What I need to do with this installer is to check whether the port 80 is available and if it is available proceed with the  installer of if it is not give an error message with the process name which is running on port 80.

I found a way to check whether the port 80 is available or not. For that I have used Ports.nsh as a plugin. http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Check_open_ports

```
${If} ${TCPPortOpen} 80
 MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP "PORT 80 is already using by another program..."
 Abort
${EndIf}
```

But with this I cannot find the running process on that port. I need to give an error message such as

```
//Skype is running on port 80 and close Skype to continue with the installation.
```

Can someone please help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since I could not find a proper way to do this in nsis I just used VBScript to check the process name and called it throug the nsis script. Follwing is the code.

//TestPort80.vbs

```
Dim WshShell, oExec, key
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("netstat -o -n -a")
key = "0.0:80"

Dim values
values = checkPortStatus(oExec, key)
portInUse = values(0)
input = values(1)

If portInUse Then
  x = InStrRev(input, " ")

  ProcessID = Mid(input, x+1)

  commandTxt = "tasklist /FI " & Chr(34) & "PID eq " & ProcessID & Chr(34)

Dim oExec2, key2
Set oExec2 = WshShell.Exec(commandTxt)
key2 = ProcessID

Dim values2
values2 = checkPortStatus(oExec2, key2)
Found = values2(0)
input2 = values2(1)

If Found Then
    y = InStr(input2, " ")
    ExeName = Left(input2, y-1)
        WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Port 80 is using by " & ExeName
End If
End If
'## If we explicitly set a Success code then we can avoid this.
WScript.Quit 512

Function checkPortStatus(oExec, key)
portInUse = false
input = ""
Do While True

     If Not oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream Then
          input = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine()
          If InStr(input, key) <> 0 Then 
        ' Found Port 80
                portInUse = true
                Exit DO
          End If
     Else
        Exit DO
     End If
     WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

Do While oExec.Status <> 1
 WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
Dim values(1)
values(0) = portInUse
values(1) = input

checkPortStatus = values

End Function
```

//Installer.nsi

```
${If} ${TCPPortOpen} 80
 GetTempFileName $0
     File /oname=$0 `TestPort80.vbs` 
     nsExec::ExecToStack `"$SYSDIR\CScript.exe" $0 //e:vbscript //B //NOLOGO`
 Pop $0
 Pop $1
 MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP '$1'
 Abort
${EndIf}
```